# Show that functions are/aren't uniformly convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'm looking over uniform convergence in my textbook and want to make sure I'm doing the problems correctly. The question is

*Determine the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ on the indicated interval, and state whether the convergence is uniform.*

a) $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$, on $[0,1]$

b) $f_n(x)= \frac{e^x}{n^2}$ on $(1, \infty)$

c) $f_n(x)=x^n-x^{2n}$ on $[0,1]$

d) $f_n(x)=\frac{2nx}{1+n+3x}$ on $[0,\infty)$.

What I have so far is

a) $f(x)=\begin{cases}
 0 &\text{if}\, x=0\\
 1 &\text{if}\, x\in(0,1]\
\end{cases}$ and that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly. Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Choose $x_n=e^{-n}$, then $\left|f(x_n)-f_n(x_n)\right|=\left|1-\sqrt[n]{e^{-n}}\right|=1-\frac{1}{e}>\frac{1}{2}\ge\varepsilon$. I believe you could also argue that since $f(x)$ is discontinuous and each $f_n(x)$ is continuous, then $f_n(x)$ cannot converge uniformly since uniform convergence preserves continuity.

b) $f(x)=0$ and that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly. Let $\varepsilon=1$. Choose $x_n=\ln(n^2)$. Then $\left|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\right|=\left|\frac{e^{\ln(n^2)}}{n^2}-0\right|=1\ge \varepsilon$.

c) $f(x)=0$ and that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly. Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4}$. Choose $x_n=\sqrt[n]\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\left|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\right|=\left|\left(\sqrt[n]\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-\left(\sqrt[n]\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}-0\right|=\frac{1}{2}-(\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}\ge \varepsilon$.

d) $f(x)=2x$ and that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly. Let $\varepsilon=1$. Choose $x_n=n$. Then $\left|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\right|=\left|\frac{2nn}{1+n+3n}-2n\right|=2n\left|\frac{n}{1+4n}-1\right|=2n\left|\frac{1+3n}{1+4n}\right|\ge2n\frac{1}{2}=n\ge1=\varepsilon$.

Comment: There is an error in (d), though whether it is an error in your math, or a transcription error as you copied the problem here, I cannot say. $k$ is a constant, so you cannot set it to $n$. Otherwise everything looks good. Very well argued.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it was a transcription error. I prefer the index n while the textbook uses k as the index.